# OneToMany JoinTable with a non Primary Key value

Tags: jakarta-ee, many-to-many, one-to-many, many-to-one, join

I'm trying to replicate Facebook's wall in Java EE.

I've got 3 tables:
User, Post, Wall.

User has an username(PK) and other fields, Post has an id(PK), an author(FK on User) and some other.
Wall is a Join Table between Post and User.

The point is that the project compiles only if I have, in Wall, both post and user as PK.
Having Post has PK and User just as a non null value won't work !

But having both of them as PK leads to a @ManyToMany, which means that the same post can be on many Walls, which is incorrect !

I've tried having just Post as PK in Wall and using this mapping :

Post:

```
@JoinTable(name = "Wall", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "username")})
@OneToMany
private User user;
```

User:

```
@ManyToOne
private Collection<Post> onWall;
```

but it says :

> The target entity of the relationship attribute [user] on the class [class entity.Post] cannot be determined.  When not using generics, ensure the target entity is defined on the relationship mapping..

What's wrong with my mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about two relationships User-to-Post, one for wall, one for authorship:

- *User* one-to-many to *Post* (posts stuck to user's wall, no join table),
- *User* one-to-many to *Post* (post's author),

with reverse relationships as needed.

For example:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="onWall")
    private Collection<Post> wall;

    // You can skip this relationship, if you don't want it
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="author")
    private Collection<Post> authoredPosts;
}

@Entity
public class Post {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="wallOwnerId")
    private User onWall;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="authorId")
    private User author;
}
```

Comment: I know, but I think that Wall isn't a regular entity. I mean, Wall has to Join data from Post with data from User, that's why I thought it as a JoinTable ! Isn't there any way to do what I asked in my question? Thanks for the reply btw :)

Comment: Good point! :) Just another question..Wouldn't this require a new field in Post table to have both Author and Owner?

Comment: @StepTNT It would, definitely. They are different relations, likely pointing to different User instances.